# "error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in ‘opcode’" pxor compiling ffmpeg with mmx flag enabled

Tags: assembly, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2005, mmx

I'm trying to compile (visual studio 2005) ffmpeg with mmx flag enabled (HAVE_MMX) but get the following error:
"error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in ‘opcode’"
And it's complaining about **xpor_r2r**

Ideas?

[Update]
Jester pointed out that it's probably a problem with the macro:
`#define         mmx_r2r(op,regs,regd) \
        __asm__ volatile (#op " %" #regs ", %" #regd)`

Directly using:
`__asm__ pxor mm7 mm7` works
Adding **volatile** (as in the macro mentioned) gives the same error, syntax error as before in **'opcode' found 'data_type'**.

Just removing **volatile** from the macro does not work, instead gives error in **'opcode' found '('**

Removing the paranthesis instead gives error in **'opcode' found 'bad_token'**

Comment: Maybe you could try a newer version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @Paul: Do you know for sure that visual studio 2005 does not support it?

Comment: No, but unless there is some good reason to stick with such an old version I would expect that a newer version would have better support for SIMD extensions.

Comment: Agree, all other parts of the system is built using vs2005 and we are moving to a newer compiler but have not reached that point yet. We could of course move to a newer compiler for this specific lib to se if that helps.

Comment: Yes - it would certainly be worth checking - I think you can still get free "Express" versions of Visual Studio 2008 and later which is useful for checking compatibility issues etc.

Comment: `xpor_r2r` is not a valid instruction in x86, but `pxor` is. If you really have that in the code maybe it's a macro that's not expanded for some reason?

Comment: @Jester: You are right, #define pxor_r2r(regs, regd)   mmx_r2r (pxor, regs, regd). I'll dig deeper into it.